# aggregate function produces error after loading memisc package

Tags: r

`aggregate` function works fine

```
aggregate(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean)
       feed   weight
1    casein 323.5833
2 horsebean 160.2000
3   linseed 218.7500
4  meatmeal 276.9091
5   soybean 246.4286
6 sunflower 328.9167
```

But after loading `library(memisc)` in R 2.14.1, the same code produces the following error

```
Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

What is the problem and how to solve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This package redefines the `aggregate` method.
There is often a warning in those cases, but since `aggregate.formula` is a hidden method, there is no warning.
You can explicitely use the initial `aggregate` function by specifying its namespace
(three colons are needed because it is a hidden method).

```
stats:::aggregate.formula(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean)
```

Comment: (+1) @Vincent Zoonekynd: Thanks a lot for your nice and helpful answer. Thanks again.